# Button problem in multi-threading Python Tkinter Serial Monitor

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, pyserial

I try to create a Serial Monitor which can send and receive messages from a Serial Port with Tkinter as GUI. I did two threads for not having a freezed GUI when the program search for a new data.

---

The Tkinter GUI is simple :

- 1 Entry for put the text to send
- 1 label for show the received message
- 1 button for send the Entry message

My problem is when I run the program, and I click on the button, nothing happend. I think the button is no longer loaded when I start my two thread. How I can do for adress this issue ?

```python
import threading
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import serial
root = tk.Tk()
COM = "COM3"
ser = serial.Serial(port=COM, baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=2)
ser.isOpen()
msg = ""


# read Serial
def ReadSerial():
    global msg
    msg = ""
    msg = ser.readline()[:-2].decode("utf-8")
    if msg != "":
        print(msg)
        
    return msg
# write Serial
def WriteSerial(sendmsg):
    print("send")
    ser.write(bytes(sendmsg, 'utf-8'))
    ReadSerial()


# Tkinter
root.title("WIP NAME")
root.geometry("650x400")
inputData = Entry(root, text="<Slave1&p>") # input for enter the message to write
entrymsg = inputData.get() # get the massage
buttonMsg = Button(root, text="send", command = WriteSerial(entrymsg)) # create a send button for send the message
readData = Label(root, text=msg) # show message in Tkinter
ReadSerial()
# show items
inputData.grid()
readData.grid()
buttonMsg.grid()


# GUI thread
def TkinterGui():
    while 1==1:
        global msg
        entrymsg = inputData.get()


# Serial thread
def SerialProgram():
    while 1==1:
        ReadSerial()
        readData.update_idletasks()


x = threading.Thread(target=TkinterGui, args=())
y = threading.Thread(target=SerialProgram, args=())
x.start()
y.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks to me that you shouldn't use the `threading` module, but rather rewrite your functions to use tkinters `after` method. Subthreading within tkinter is generally not a good idea and is very error-prone

Comment: `command = WriteSerial(entrymsg)` should be `command = lambda: WriteSerial(entrymsg)` or `command = lambda: WriteSerial(inputData.get())`.  Using later will not require to run `TkinterGui()`.

Comment: I have already tried this but the problem is that without multi-threading, the Tkinter screen freezes too much because it has to do the functions and then re-simulate the screen. @oskros

Comment: Thank you @acw1668, it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realy thank you @acw1668, I work on this project for a week already.
That the correct command :

`buttonMsg = Button(root, text="send", command = lambda: WriteSerial(inputData.get()))`

and the entire code :

```python
import threading
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import serial
root = tk.Tk()
COM = "COM3"
ser = serial.Serial(port=COM, baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=2)
ser.isOpen()
msg = ""


# read Serial
def ReadSerial():
    global msg
    msg = ""
    msg = ser.readline()[:-2].decode("utf-8")
    if msg != "":
        print(msg)
        
    return msg
# write Serial
def WriteSerial(sendmsg):
    print("send")
    ser.write(bytes(sendmsg, 'utf-8'))
    ReadSerial()


# Tkinter
root.title("WIP NAME")
root.geometry("650x400")
inputData = Entry(root, text="<Slave1&p>") # input for enter the message to write
entrymsg = inputData.get() # get the massage
buttonMsg = Button(root, text="send", command = lambda: WriteSerial(inputData.get())) # create a send button for send the message
readData = Label(root, text=msg) # show message in Tkinter
ReadSerial()
# show items
inputData.grid()
readData.grid()
buttonMsg.grid()


# GUI thread
def TkinterGui():
    while 1==1:
        global msg
        entrymsg = inputData.get()


# Serial thread
def SerialProgram():
    while 1==1:
        ReadSerial()
        readData.update_idletasks()


x = threading.Thread(target=TkinterGui, args=())
y = threading.Thread(target=SerialProgram, args=())
x.start()
y.start()

root.mainloop()
```

P.S.: Sory if my english is not extremely understandable, I'm French :)

Comment: Actually you don't need to run `TkinterGui()`.